# Using Python to Concatenate Paragraphs Underneath Heading

Tags: python, regex

I have a file where headings can look something like this:

=== Heading 1 ===

text

text

text

===Heading 2===

text

text

'' Heading 3''

text

text

'''Heading 4'''

text

text

text

I am trying to concatenate each paragraph along with its heading, given the example above, the final outcome should be something like this:

=== Heading 1 === text text text

===Heading 2=== text text

'' Heading 3'' text text

'''Heading 4''' text text text

What is the best way to go about doing this, using python?

Comment: Try to categorize first. What constitutes a heading? How is that different from body text? From your examples, it looks like a header starts with a punctuation mark, so consider `line.startswith(string.punctuation)`

Comment: Then consider reading the file line by line, splitting into groups as you go. The result of this initial parse should be a list of lists, where each inner list is a list of lines from your document you intend to concatenate together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to categorize first. What constitutes a heading? How is that different from body text? From your examples, it looks like a header starts with a punctuation mark, so consider

```
import string

def is_header(line):
    return line.startswith(string.punctuation)
```

Then consider reading the file line by line, splitting into groups as you go. The result of this initial parse should be a list of lists, where each inner list is a list of lines from your document you intend to concatenate together.

```
parsed_lines = []
cur_p = []
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        if is_header(line) and cur_p:
            parsed_lines.append(cur_p)
            cur_p = []
        else:
            cur_p.append(line.strip())
```

Now you should have a list of lists like:

```
[ ["===Some Header===", "body text", "more body text", "even more"],
  ["''Another header''", "wow such body", "many text"],
  ... ]
```

And you can use `str.join` to tie them together.

```
result = []

for p in parsed_lines:
    result.append(' '.join(p))
```

This gives you

```
# result is
["===Some Header=== body text more body text even more",
 "''Another header'' wow such body many text", ... ]
```

I'm sure you can figure out how to use `str.join` to tie `result` up the way you like it.